# iPhone Navigation-Based application - some global toolbar questions

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, global, uitoolbar, mainwindow

I started iPhone development two months ago, so I can't call myself "expert" ;-) But I learned a lot in these two months, a lot here from stackoverflow :) 
I'm working on an iPhone app which is based on the "Navigation-Based application" app template. My RootViewController is, of course, an UITableView. From that TableView, I can navigate to some views and one TableView.
I'm using a global toolbar, it's called in the RootViewController. Buttons are added to it in the view that needs the buttons. 
Now, I have some questions regarding the use of the toolbar

1. I insert a flexible space with that code:

   UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

and a fixed space like this:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:self action:nil];
```

My question: The flexible space is working, but how do I tell the fixed space which width it should have?

2. I noticed that my Todo-App "Things" uses a global toolbar with switching button sets. But in Things, there's some kind of fading effect when the button set is changing. How can I do that in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the items on the toolbar and have it fade between the two sets, try this instance method of `UIToolbar`:

`- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated`

You basically keep the two sets of toolbar items in two arrays.

Answer (score 4):

The docs say:

**UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace**

> Blank space to add between other
>   items. Only the *width* property is used
>   when this value is set.

Set the item's width property.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it's working now :-)
So, question 1 is solved.
Answers to question 2 are still welcome ;-)

Comment: You can edit your own question rather than adding replies as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to do that in the future.